# How to add javascript code in cakePHP view

Tags: cakephp

I have written the following piece of code in my view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function filldetails()
{
    document.getElementById('FirstName').value  = "hjshjsh"; 
}
</script>
echo $this->Form->select('students',$student_name,array('onchange' =>filldetails()));
```

but i am getting an error message

```
call to undefined function filldetails()
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Since the JS function `filledetails` is being called, it would suggest that you haven't defined it properly. Can you provide more information on where you've defined the filldetails() function and ensure that it's wrapped in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`. I don't think it's a cake php error per se

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be `'onchange' => 'filldetails()'`

Answer (score 0):

Unless your project has a specific reason to avoid JS frameworks, you will avoid a lot of long-term headaches by using jQuery instead of pure Javascript.

Rewrite your view thus:

```
<?php
  $selectDomId = $this->Form->domId('students');
  $firstnameDomId = $this->Form->domId('Student.first_name');

  $this->Html->scriptBlock("
      jQuery(function($){
        $('#{$selectDomId}').change(function(event){
          $('#{$firstnameDomId}').val( $(this).val() );
        });
      });
  ",array('inline'=>false));
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->select('students',$student_name,$this->Form->domId(array(),'students'))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Student.first_name')?>
```

The jQuery takes care of the `onChange` event handler, so it doesn't clutter your HTML, by hooking onto your dropdown menu's change event.

The use of [`Helper::domId`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/helper#method-HelperdomId) means you don't have to worry about *how* CakePHP's helpers generate their `id` attributes, which is a net win in reliability and maintainability.

Comment: But it is not working , do i need to import some jquery library files

Comment: hi Daniel, on change the value is not filled up.can you please help me to solve this issue.